# This application contains an app extension with a bundle identifier that conflicts with the bundle identifier of another app

Tags: ios, xcode

When I try to build via xcode to my iPhone, it succeed but after that it show warning "This application contains an app extension with a bundle identifier that conflicts with the bundle identifier of another app or app extension already installed". what must i do to succeed build to my iPhone?

Comment: Change bundle identifier?

Comment: @mag_zbc, already try but did not succeed

Comment: I'm stuck in the same problem. Have you found any answers to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't have two applications with the same bundle id installed on your phone.

Your build **did succeed**, that's the installation process that failed. I have two suggestions:

- Change the bundle identifier of your current app so it doesn't conflict with other apps
- Delete the app with the same bundle identifier

Comment: Maybe watch if you're building the right target, else Clean Project → Restart Xcode → Restart iPhone → Restart Mac _(try to install on each arrow)_

Comment: already Clean Project → Restart Xcode → Restart iPhone → Restart Mac but did not work too

Answer (score 0):

The error seems self explanatory ; you have multiple apps extensions in your solution that have the same bundle identifier.

Check all your `info.plist` files, and try adding `.ext` (for example), after the bundle identifiers in the app extensions that have the same identifier as your main app.

Comment: it must same between Parent App Bundle Identifier and Embedded Binary Bundle Identifier

Comment: Oh yes that is true ! Are you sure you've set up the right targets for each project?